# Hasn't Love Live occurred in previous years?

Tags: love-live

at the start of Season 2 of *Love Live! School Idol Project* the first years are running around the place trying to find Honaka to tell here there is a second Love Live competition noting that the first one was so popular that organizers decided to hold a second one.

But it was my impression Love Live was held before Season 1 since Hanayo and Nico already knew about it when μ's formed. so hasn't Love Live occurred in previous years?

Comment: incase if it matters, i'm reading the NISA English Subtitles

Comment: They held Love Live on season 1 but μ's didn't participate then

Comment: @Darjeeling i know but i was on the impression that it wasn't the first one, that it has happened before season 1

Answer (score 2):

Love Live was indeed been held before.

> The first Love Live was won by ARISE.

which is why ARISE was the favourite to win the 2nd Love Live.

Comment: i think i didn't make something clear which lead to both you and Darjeeling being confused. i am referring to how Hanayo and Nico knew about it in Season 1 as i thought there had been more *before* the one that occurred in Season 1

Comment: They know from the advertisements. Hanayo is an idol-otaku. Nico is the president of the idol research club. It is not surprising at all that they would know.